# Is there anyway to view history of cURL?

Tags: curl, terminal, libcurl

Using shell I made some cURL requests. History command usually shows most of the thing executed in shell, but in this case I wasn't able to view requests logs I just made.

Is there any way I can view cURL logs? I know requests made to endpoints and servers must have logged them but I need to know the way I cannot find these previous records just by using some command like history.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this?  Any linux/unix shell has command history, and should have the curl commands you have issued in the past.  Are you looking for the actual _content_ from the curl commands executed in the past?

Comment: @mjuarez I am only looking for curl commands that are executed in post, and they are not shown in history nor even logged.

Answer (score 0):

Curl has no logs.
If you want a log file for curl, go in your $HOME/.bashrc or whatever shell you are using and setup the following:
alias curl='curl 1>/path/to/histfile 2>&1'
alias '/usr/bin/curl'= 'curl'